# How to search for a String containing certain Characters in a Set?

Tags: ios, swift, search, set

How can I search a `Set` to get the result below?

```
let brands: Set = ["apple", "microsoft", "hp", "lenovo", "asus", "qualcomm", "intel", "kingston"]

findValueinSet(brands, withCharacters: "a", "u") // returns "asus"
```

Comment: Is that you want to find all elements of the set that contain both letters "a" and "u"?

Comment: Does the order should be the same or "qualcomm" should be included ?

Comment: I want to add all containing a and u. Result should be asus and qualcomm

Comment: order is not important

Answer (score 2):

You can filter both sets and arrays with

```
filter(setOrArray, predicate)
```

the result is an array in either case. Whether all characters of
a given set are contained in a string can be determined with

```
searchCharacters.isSubsetOf(string)
```

Together:

```
let brands: Set<String> = ["apple", "microsoft", "hp", "lenovo", "asus", "qualcomm", "intel", "kingston"]
let searchCharacters = Set("au")

let filtered = filter(brands) { searchCharacters.isSubsetOf($0) }
println(filtered) // [qualcomm, asus]
```

This works if `brands` is an array or a set of `String`.

*Remark:* You should not define a literal array with 68k elements
in the Swift source code. Better use a resource file (a simple text
file or a property list) and load the array from there on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This will return an array from a set with strings containing letters from another set:

```
let brands: Set<String> = ["apple", "microsoft", "hp", "lenovo", "asus", "qualcomm", "intel", "kingston"]
let filters: Set<Character> = ["a", "u"]

func predicate(item: String, filters:Set<Character>) -> Bool {
  for single in filters {
    if contains(item, single) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}


let found = filter(brands, {predicate($0, filters)})
```